# Get gridview triggered with file uploaded details

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I'm handing fileupload in Modalpopup window.  On upload button click, I need to show the details of the file in my gridview.  On button click, i need the gridview to trigger with the file info.  Any idea how i can do it?